# j_spring_security_check 404

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

We are trying to upgrade an existing web application from Spring 2.x to Spring 3 and believe we are on the last issue before everything is working again. We use CAS, and can get to the JASIG CAS login, however it goes to a 404 error when we log in. We had our server admin pull the Catalina logs from the CAS server and it states that login was successful and that it is returning to the application. However in the debug output from the tomcat server it states Access Denied for anonymous user, which I'm not.

Web.xml snippet

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name> 
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties</param-value> 
</context-param>
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name> 
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class> 
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name> 
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
</filter-mapping>
```

ApplicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:edu/umt/brp/spring/run-env.xml"/>


<!-- NEW SECURITY (Begin) -->
<security:http access-denied-page="/myAccessDeniedPage" entry-point-ref="casProcessingFilterEntryPoint">
    <security:port-mappings>
    <!--<security:port-mapping http="8080" https="8081"/> -->
    <security:port-mapping http="8080" https="443"/> 
    </security:port-mappings>


    <security:intercept-url pattern="/infoGriz.html*" access="ROLE_EMPLOYEE" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**/frameset**" access="ROLE_EMPLOYEE" />
<!--        <security:logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="https://logintest.umt.edu/cas/logout" invalidate-session="true"/> -->
    <!--  next line may fix problem --> 
    <security:logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="${casLogoutUrl}" invalidate-session="true"/>
</security:http>     
<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" jsr250-annotations="enabled" />

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider ref="casAuthenticationProvider" />
</security:authentication-manager>

<security:ldap-server id="ldapServer" url="${ldapUrl}"/>

<bean id="userService" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.LdapUserDetailsService">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean id="userSearch" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch">
            <constructor-arg index="0" value="cn=users,dc=umt,dc=edu"/>
            <constructor-arg index="1" value="(uid={0})"/>
            <constructor-arg index="2" ref="ldapServer" />
        </bean>     
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="edu.umt.brp.security.AuthoritiesPopulator">
            <constructor-arg ref="ldapServer" />
            <constructor-arg value="cn=groups,dc=umt,dc=edu" />
            <property name="groupSearchFilter" value="(uniqueMember={0})"/>
            <property name="searchSubtree" value="true"/>

            <property name="grouperServiceUrl" value="${grouperServiceUrl}"/>
            <property name="grouperUser" value="${grouperUser}"/>
            <property name="grouperPass" value="${grouperPass}"/>

        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="userDetailsMapper">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.PersonContextMapper"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="serviceProperties" class="org.springframework.security.cas.ServiceProperties">
    <property name="service" value="${applicationHost}/infoGriz/j_spring_cas_security_check"/> 
    <property name="sendRenew" value="false"/>
</bean> 

<bean id="casProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <property name="authenticationFailureHandler">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
            <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="http://www.google.com"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="casProcessingFilterEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="loginUrl" value="${casLoginUrl}"/>
    <property name="serviceProperties" ref="serviceProperties"/>
</bean>

<bean id="casAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.CasAuthenticationProvider" >
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userService"/>
    <property name="serviceProperties" ref="serviceProperties" />

    <property name="ticketValidator">
        <bean class="org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator">
            <constructor-arg index="0" value="${casValidateUrl}" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="key" value="an_id_for_this_auth_provider_only"/>
</bean>
<!-- NEW SECURITY (End) -->
```

We have another web application that is already on Spring 3, and spring security 3.0.2 that we are using as a model, but nothing seems to be any different between the two. Let me know if any other files would help.

Thanks,

Ian

Answer (score 0):

Based on Spring Security 3 [reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/cas.html), you need to also add *CAS auth filter* to security configuration:

```
<security:http ... >
    <security:custom-filter position="CAS_FILTER" ref="casProcessingFilter" />
</security:http>
```

A question that I have is what's relation between `/infoGriz.html*` and `/infoGriz/j_spring_cas_security_check`? If you expect the `intercept-url` tag to catch the second one, it does not!